# How to start a basic WebRTC data channel?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

How to start a basic WebRTC data channel?

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't even seem to try and connect. Im sure I am just missing something basic.

```
var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.msRTCPeerConnection;

var peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
    iceServers: [
        {url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302'},
        {url: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'},
        {url: 'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302'},
        {url: 'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302'},
    ]
});
peerConnection.ondatachannel  = function () {
    console.log('peerConnection.ondatachannel');
};
peerConnection.onicecandidate = function () {
    console.log('peerConnection.onicecandidate');
};

var dataChannel = peerConnection.createDataChannel('myLabel', {
});

dataChannel.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log('dataChannel.onerror');
};

dataChannel.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log('dataChannel.onmessage');
};

dataChannel.onopen = function () {
    console.log('dataChannel.onopen');
    dataChannel.send('Hello World!');
};

dataChannel.onclose = function () {
    console.log('dataChannel.onclose');
};
console.log(peerConnection, dataChannel);
```

Comment: It's not trying to connect because your code isn't doing anything to connect. You have to initiate an offer/answer exchange with another peer. What are you using for signaling? What initiates the call to the other connection?

Comment: @xdumaine yea that is where I am a bit unsure, any info on how to do this? Is it possible to do it without a server (i.e. p2p)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WebRTC assumes you have a way to signal (send an offer-string to, and receive an answer-string from) whomever you wish to contact. Without some server, how will you do that?

To illustrate, here's some code that does everything but that (works in Firefox and Chrome 45):

```js
var config = { iceServers: [{ urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }]};
var dc, pc = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
pc.ondatachannel = e => {
  dc = e.channel;
  dc.onopen = e => (log("Chat!"), chat.select());
  dc.onmessage = e => log(e.data);
}

function createOffer() {
  button.disabled = true;
  pc.ondatachannel({ channel: pc.createDataChannel("chat") });
  pc.createOffer().then(d => pc.setLocalDescription(d)).catch(failed);
  pc.onicecandidate = e => {
    if (e.candidate) return;
    offer.value = pc.localDescription.sdp;
    offer.select();
    answer.placeholder = "Paste answer here";
  };
};

offer.onkeypress = e => {
  if (e.keyCode != 13 || pc.signalingState != "stable") return;
  button.disabled = offer.disabled = true;
  var obj = { type:"offer", sdp:offer.value };
  pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(obj))
  .then(() => pc.createAnswer()).then(d => pc.setLocalDescription(d))
  .catch(failed);
  pc.onicecandidate = e => {
    if (e.candidate) return;
    answer.focus();
    answer.value = pc.localDescription.sdp;
    answer.select();
  };
};

answer.onkeypress = e => {
  if (e.keyCode != 13 || pc.signalingState != "have-local-offer") return;
  answer.disabled = true;
  var obj = { type:"answer", sdp:answer.value };
  pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(obj)).catch(failed);
};

chat.onkeypress = e => {
  if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
  dc.send(chat.value);
  log(chat.value);
  chat.value = "";
};

var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<p>" + msg + "</p>";
var failed = e => log(e + ", line " + e.lineNumber);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/webrtc/adapter/master/adapter.js"></script>
<button id="button" onclick="createOffer()">Offer:</button>
<textarea id="offer" placeholder="Paste offer here"></textarea><br>
Answer: <textarea id="answer"></textarea><br><div id="div"></div>
Chat: <input id="chat"></input><br>
```

Open this page in a second tab, and you can chat from one tab to the other (or to a different machine around the world). What stinks is that you must get the offer there yourself:

- Press the `Offer` button in Tab A (only) and wait 1-20 seconds till you see the offer-text,
- copy-paste the offer-text from Tab A to Tab B, and hit `Enter`
- copy-paste the answer-text that appears from Tab B to Tab A, and hit `Enter`.

You should now be able to chat between tabs, without a server.

As you can see, this is a sub-par experience, which is why you need some basic websocket server to pass offer/answer (as well as trickle ice candidates if you want connecting to happen fast) between A and B, to get things started. Once you have a connection, you can use data-channels for this, with a little extra work.

Comment: Nice answer, if you can flesh it out a bit, tidy it up, and make it work cross browser I will bounty you 500 rep.

Comment: I've updated the answer to work in Chrome 45 using the [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) polyfill. Hope that helps! Your offer is generous but my interest is in promoting the standard, so I'm loath to use legacy callbacks or lose the arrow functions, as I've found that makes WebRTC examples extremely unreadable. - If you have any trouble with the differences don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: @jib What is the point of the following line: 
`pc.ondatachannel({ channel: pc.createDataChannel("chat") });`?

  In other examples, `ondatachannel` is always used as a callback? What's the point of calling it with an object?

Comment: @Lars It's just calling the callback directly on one side; an overly clever way to run the same datachannel initialization code on both ends, since the API by default is asymmetric. In modern code I recommend using the more symmetric and declarative `negotiated` API instead: https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/ovbc1uzf/